# Explicit SSL / TLS version selection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, tls1.2

I am aware on **when** we should explicitly set a supported TLS version through [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) property using C# & .NET.

But what I am not aware is **why** we should do this ?

> As per MSDN: This property selects the version of the Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use for new
>   connections that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS)
>   scheme only; existing connections are not changed.

As far as I aware, the agreement of SSL/TLS versions between client and server is agreed upon TLS handshake.

**Question:** Can someone explain me the relevance of explicit version selection? **Or** Why we should mentioned the supported TLS version when such negotiation was suppose to be performed at the stage of TLS handshake?

Comment: So you don't have to rely on the implicit implementation, or remember what it was in a certain Framework version, or trust that a protocol set is available in any specific deployment. Also, having it explicitly set, renders the code itself explicit on what it is meant to support. Different protocols require special care and specific implementations. You can see that looking at the first line of code. Plus, the default implementation not always work, especially when Tls1.2 is in use.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yes, of course. But if a protocol version you need to target is not available in a machine/platform, you can give feedback since you receive a `NotSupported` exception. On the _the default does work_ I don't agree. I know - directly - that some servers do not answer correctly or raise errors if `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is not explicitly set to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.

Comment: This was also asked at security.stackexchange.com and is [answered there](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176829/explicit-ssl-tls-version-selection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answered by Steffen Ullrich ([SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176829/explicit-ssl-tls-version-selection))

This is not used to select a specific protocol version but to set a list of allowed protocol versions. Typically you want to have TLS 1.2 and higher, maybe TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0 for compatibility reasons but you don't want to allow SSLv3 or lower. By using this API you can tune which protocols are allowed within the following TLS handshakes.